# Another mod_rewrite trailing slash question

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, sourceforge

I have the following rewrite rules in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/?$ /?action=news&start=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^man/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/?$ /?action=man&page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/?$ /?action=$1 [L]
```

All of then end with a `/?` to check for an optional trailing slash. This works - it means I can use either `http://www.site.com/news/` or `http://www.site.com/news` to get to the `news` page, which is what I want. The problem is that, while `http://www.site.com/news/` works fine and redirects silently and all that fun stuff, `http://www.site.com/news` is visibly redirected to `http://www.site.com/news/?action=news` for some reason. They both come up with the same site, but for some reason if I leave off the trailing slash, the URL changes and looks all nasty.

Any ideas what's going on with this? I have no other rules in my `.hyaccess` file. I'll also point out that `http://www.site.com/news/0` and `http://www.site.com/news/0/` do not suffer from the same problem. Both of them redirect invisibly to `http://www.site.com/?action=news&start=0`, which is what I want. It only seems to be a problem with that third rule.

If it helps any, the site is on SourceForge.net.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A wild guess: there is a directory named "news", and the the automatic Apache directory "add a trailing slash" redirect is kicking in and interacting with your RewriteRule in a weird way.  If that's the case,

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

may help.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. I'm not sure why this happens, but Apache is a complex program and I'm willing to write it off as fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [`MultiViews`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options) is causing this behavior. Try to disable this option:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

---

Another guess: remove the leading slash in the substitution.