# Problem changing URL structure with Htaccess and php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a problem fixing the URL on my website, http://www.abelputra.com: I want to change `www.abelputra.com/software.php` into `www.abelputra.com/software`.

I have read a tutorial that suggests the following:

For .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ ([a-zA-Z0-9_-] +) $ index.php? Key = $ 1
RewriteRule ^ ([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php? Key = $ 1
```

Then in php:

index.php --->

```
$Key=$ _GET ['key'];

if ($key == 'home')
{
    include ('index.php'); // Home page
}
else if ($ key == 'software')
{
    include ('software.php'); //
}
else if ($ key == 'webdesign')
{
    include ('webdesign.php'); //
}
```

The problem is that when I implemented the menu with software.php and index.php to call the page:

`www.abelputra.com/index.php?key=software`

what happens is that the page that's shown is two pages, with both software.php and index.php page underneath.

Is it because I'm calling "include ()" functions?

index.php structures:

1. Header
2. Content -> contains the opening words
3. Footer

software.php structure:

1. Header
2. Content -> contains an explanation of my software
3. Footer

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand correctly, but if you just want to rewrite the URLs (like removing the .php extension), you don't need to implement a gateway script or to change the logic code of your homepage (except modifying the URLs).

As an example, the following will allow to access your free tips with
abelputra.com/freetips/185

```
RewriteRule ^freetips/(\d+)$ freetips_det.php?tip=$1 [L]
```

General extension removing is a well known topic, discussed here for example:

[htaccess code to remove extension AND add+force trailing slash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068595)

Comment: my problem is how to implement it in php

Comment: my solution is how you don't need to, as your homepage is already working and you just want to change some URLs

Comment: Yes, my web is working. but I see them eliminate most other websites .php and turn it into a folder. and according to me not omit the php extensions.
I just do not know how to implement it in my php scripts.

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]

RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f

RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```