# redirect old site to new site using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

Please help with htaccess. I need to redirect my old site to a new site.
if anyone visits the old site, it will redirect to my new site. how can I implement that using htaccess?
Thanks

but do you know a simple code to do something like this. for example my old site pages is www.old.com/homerun.html to redirect to new page, www.new.com/homerun/, www.old.com/themes/newpage.html to www.new.com/themes/newpage/ , so basically it will replace the domain and remove the .html

Answer (score 2):

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.example.com/
```

That should do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this redirect generator: http://www.htaccessredirect.net/

Comment: thanks. let me try that. but do you know a simple code to do something like this. for example my old site pages is www.old.com/homerun.html to redirect to new page, www.new.com/homerun/, www.old.com/themes/newpage.html to www.new.com/themes/newpage/ , so basically it will replace the domain and remove the .html

Comment: May [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068595/htaccess-code-to-remove-extension-and-addforce-trailing-slash) help you.