# Subdomain to new domain redirection

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I need simple code to do something like this.

For example my old site page is `www.old.com/homerun.html`, I want to redirect to a new page `www.new.com/homerun/`, or `www.old.com/themes/newpage.html` to `www.new.com/themes/newpage/`.

So basically it will replace the domain and remove the `.html`.

could this be done on htaccess?

Comment: Why do you ask the same question twice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574457/redirect-old-site-to-new-site-using-htaccess
down vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like the following (on the old host, root path)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.+?)(.html)$ http://www.new.com/$1/ [L,R]
```

Comment: @therealsix: You can get away without the greedy modifier, yes.  Force of habit to match the minimal amount before the `.html` - if there was more afterwards it would have been necessary.

Comment: I still don't understand what its supposed to do. Would .+? be equal to .*

Comment: @therealsix: The `?` is a non-greedy modifier, it inverts the greediness of the `+` symbol, so that it takes as few characters as possible to achieve the match, rather than as many.  As I said, it could be left out here.