# Remove .php extension from url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am required to remove .php extension and query string as well from url by rewriting the url
I know this can be done in .htaccess file
I have this in my .htaccess file so far

```
            RewriteEngine on
            DirectoryIndex Home.html

            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
            RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

            # if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            # otherwise forward it to index.html
            RewriteRule .* Home.html
```

now the url
example.com/blog.php?post=12&comment=3
can be accessed by 
example.com/blog.php/post/12/comment/3
but i want to remove .php extension as well 
this must be accessible through this url
example.com/blog/post/13/comment/3

Any help?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068595/htaccess-code-to-remove-extension-and-addforce-trailing-slash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searches for everything except **.** after **/**

```
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: I tried on XAMPP it worked. Could you try this rule
 `RedirectMatch ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)$ http://www.google.com?q=$1.php`