# How to get rid of .php extension in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to do a `mod-rewrite` in my `.htaccess` to get rid of the ".php" file extension.

So basically, here is my site right now: http://www.example.com/about.php

Here is what I want it to be: http://www.example.com/about

Is there a way to do this in my .htaccess using `mod-rewrite`? Thanks so much!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068595/htaccess-code-to-remove-extension-and-addforce-trailing-slash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! If you ever want this to work for a ".html" extension, you should change the ".php" to ".html"

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

The line with !-d checks that it's not a directory, the line with -f checks that the requested file is a .php file.

To display this though, you need to link to it like this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/about"></a>
```

Instead of:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/about.php"></a>
```

Because then it will just display the URL as about.php.

Hope this helped anyone looking to do this!