# Remove .php extesion with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to remove my `.php` when someone visits a gallery on a client site. I found the following code that enables that but my `.jpg`s display "image cannot be displayed".

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]`
```

Any recommendations?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get rid of .php extension in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203953/how-to-get-rid-of-php-extension-in-htaccess)

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove `.php` extensions completely from your file to try to avoid a **infinite loop**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

This code will work in `Root/.htaccess`, 
Make sure to change the `RewriteBase` if you want to place this into a `.htaccess` file in a sub directory.

On Apache 2.4 and later, you can use the END flag to prevent a infinite loop error. The following example should work the same as the above solution on Apache 2.4.

**TRY THIS ALSO:**

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,END]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, which is easier

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```