# .htaccess redirect according to url

Tags: .htaccess

In my hosting account, I have domains. One is located at the root and the other is in the /example/ folder. Here is the redirect code in my main .htaccess file, which works fine apart from the function I just described. This function was working previously, and has mysteriously stopped-

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/example(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
# Rewrite /example to http://example.com

# Remove .php from file names and force added slash
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068595/htaccess-code-to-remove-extension-and-addforce-trailing-slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.php
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ $0/ [L,R=301]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What function does work? And what function has stopped working?

Comment: @OlafDietsche The main purpose of my .htaccess file is to redirect /about/ to /about.php, and this is working. Redirecting /example/ to http://example.com is **not** working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the leading slash, like this:

```
RewriteRule ^example(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Oops, it does. I had an .htaccess file in the /example/ directory that was overriding it. Thanks for the help!