# remove .php from file using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to tream .php from every url
Like `localhost/index.php` ---> `localhost/index`
But I also want `localhost/index/` to work too....

Here is the current code I am using

```
#for hiding.php extension
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1\.php [NC]
############################-------- END ---------########################
```

Can anybody suggest the changes?

Comment: Check out this q&a: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068595/htaccess-code-to-remove-extension-and-addforce-trailing-slash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```