# mod_rewrite rewrite rule redirecting browser url when trailing slash is not present

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with a mod_rewrite rule.

basically, I'm trying to hide an ugly folder name. It works fine if I include a trailing slash, but if I DON'T have the slash, it redirects (is that the proper term, where it actually changes the browser url?) to the ugly folder name.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^AMN/?(.*)$ _map.AMN/index.php?page=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

So basically, if I put in http://example.com/AMN/ with the trailing slash, it works as desired: the browser shows the content in _map.AMN while leaving the pretty url. BUT if I put in http://example.com/AMN without the trailing slash, it redirects the url in the browser to be the undesired http://example.com/_map.AMN

I saw some other questions where it was suggested that the problem would be having a folder named "AMN" in the directory, but this is not the case (at least within this subdomain). Here is the question which did NOT do the trick: [Another mod_rewrite trailing slash question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550587/another-mod-rewrite-trailing-slash-question)

Any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Lame. Firefox was caching the .htaccess file. My changes weren't even taking place. Works fine in Safari.

I thought .htaccess was intended to be read each time...

not so...