# URL rewrite shows query string to client

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm implementing friendly-URLs using mod_rewrite in Apache HTTPD. My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !((.php|.htm|.css|.jpg|.png|.gif|.js|.ico)|/static/|/uploads/)
RewriteRule (.*) /main.php?path=$1 [QSA,L]
```

(I know it's a bit of a mess, it's related to legacy code that I'll be fixing later)

This works perfectly if the user puts in a URL that looks like

> http://example.com/test/

However, if the user forgets the trailing slash

> http://example.com/test

then they get redirected to

> http://example.com/test/?path=test

This makes the URLs quite ugly, and I'd like to fix it, however I don't have enough of an understanding of mod_rewrite to know what's wrong. Any chance anyone could help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening due to `mod_dir` adding a trailing slash in front of directories. You should use `RewriteCond` to skip rewriting existing files/directories like this:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /main.php?path=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /main.php?path=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: This appears to have completely disabled the rewrite engine, and now visiting http://example.com/test gives a 404 error. To clarify it should perform an internal redirect to http://example.com/main.php?path=test.

EDIT: Hmm, I did some more testing and it looks like your mod_dir diagnosis was spot on, as the issue only takes effect when the path to be rewritten actually exists in the WWW directory. I might just move all those sorts of directories into a bts folder, should fix it.

Comment: Is `/test` a directory by any chance?

Comment: Yeah, I just discovered that this was the issue. I tried doing DirectorySlash Off but it doesn't seem to have helped...

Comment: Keep `DirectorySlash On` for security reasons. Do you want to send real directories to `/main.php?path=` also?

Comment: Hmm, still no luck, updated rules still cause the rewrite engine to be completely ignored, always. I guess it's easy enough for me to just move all my folders out of WWW though, so not a massive problem.

Comment: Hmm, I just found out this question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550587/another-mod-rewrite-trailing-slash-question.

I've already tried turning off DirectorySlash though and it didn't work, no idea why...

Comment: Your answer gave me an idea, and I tidied up my .htaccess file and directory structure, eliminating the issue. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I try not to include `DirectorySlash Off` in my answers since that is considered a security risk.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I rearranged my directory structure and tidied up my .htaccess file to simply contain

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /main.php?path=$1 [QSA]
```

This does mean I'll have to do some more manual 404 error handling, but that's not really a big issue for me as the nature of my URL structure meant I'd have had to do that anyway.

Thanks heaps to anubhava for helping me work through this issue, I've marked his answer as correct even though it was really his comments that helped me.

EDIT: It's very important to use REQUEST_FILENAME instead of REQUEST_URI for the RewriteConds. I'm not sure why, but it doesn't work if you use the wrong ones.